# How to create a billing plan having period of more than 12 months?

Tags: php, paypal

**Paypal Docs**
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/payments.billing-plans/#plan.*create
payment_definitions -> frequency_interval* is required parameter and have following description "How frequently the customer should be charged. It can't be more than 12 months."

If that is the case, How to create a billing plan more than a year in Paypal?

Comment: The `frequency_interval`is to define if the user is charged every month or in another frequency. I believe the option you're looking for is the `type` parameter. But can you explain exactly the type of billing plan you want to create so I could give a better example? :)

Comment: I belive the "It can't be more than 12 months" message is in the case you set the `frequency` to month. You can't put more than 12 month in that case. But it doesn't seem to apply to the other options (`week`, `year`,...). Than you have `cycles` to define the amount of times the user would be charged. But if you set the `type` to infinite there's no limit to the amount of times.

Comment: Tried, changed the type to "INFINITE" and $paymentDefinition->setName( 'Regular Payments' )
            ->setType( 'REGULAR' )
            ->setFrequency( 'Year' )
            ->setFrequencyInterval( "3" )
            ->setCycles( "0" )
            ->setAmount( new Currency( array( 'value' => 500, 'currency' => 'USD' ) ) );  got error in log "issue":"Frequency more than year is not supported"

Answer (score 0):

you can specify total_cycles value up to 999 according to their doc:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-billing_cycle

in the previous version which is currently deprecated you could set up cycles to zero.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/#definition-payment_definition